# Console Height and Width in Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, console

I'm using OS X so I installed Visual Studio for Mac. I'm programming console Apps. The Problem is, that when I try to set the console window `height` and `width` that I get an **Exception**:

**`System.NotSupportedException - Specified method is not supported`**.

Searching through the net I found out, that's because of the terminal of Mac OS. I didn't really find a fix and most post in different forums are bla bla. I would like to know if someone of you has made the same experience and maybe knows how to solve the problem so to expand the size of the console? 
Thx for your time!
Regards